# The complete() method in java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, language-design

The `complete()` method in the Calendar class performs the following operations:

```
protected void complete()
```

> Fills in any unset fields in the calendar fields. First, the
> computeTime() method is called if the time value (millisecond offset
> from the Epoch) has not been calculated from calendar field values.
> Then, the computeFields() method is called to calculate all calendar
> field values.

the `complete()` method has the following code:

```
protected void complete()
    {
        if (!isTimeSet)
        updateTime();
        if (!areFieldsSet || !areAllFieldsSet) {
            computeFields(); // fills in unset fields
            areAllFieldsSet = areFieldsSet = true;
        }
    }
```

My question is what is the point of this circular work?? First values from

```
protected int[] fields
```

are used to update the value of

```
long time
```

using the `computeTime()` method. And then the value of `time` is used to update values in `fields` using `computeFields()`. The value in both `time` and `fields` will be in sync after the call to `computeTime()` itself, right?? or am i missing something here??

For those who might ask why is it so important, well it is because the order in which the time is recomputed in Calendar often changes the time we get from `getTime()` (or so i have read)!!

Comment: `the complete() method has the following code` - Beware, that it's implementation-dependent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not circular.

Imagine you have a `Calendar` object with some, but not all, fields set.  This method will (a) compute and save the epoch (`long time`) from the fields that *are* set, then (b) set all the unset fields to be consistent with the epoch it just computed.

So when the method completes you'll have a `Calendar` with all fields filled in and consistent.  That is a different, better state of the object from where you started.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum is very right.. just to add some more, u can't directly compute the values of missing fields from the available fields, u have to go through the process of computing the time value and then filling up the missing fields from that value.